# Use DATEVALUE in formula on REFERENCED date/time field

Tags: reporting, formula, datetime, date, custom-report-type

I have the following formula on the case object:

**TODAY () - DATEVALUE(Object2__r.LastModifiedDate)**

But after I insert this field on the report nothing shows (I want show the day difference between last modified date and today) I have checked that the date is definitely there and populated but it only shows **"-"** in the report column. Also tried in classic mode but nothing...

There is no help to this in the documentation.
Can this trick be done with ".r" referenced fields? It works fine on another field on the same object:

**TODAY () - DATEVALUE(LastModifiedDate)**

Comment: According to the [tailhead documentation](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/improve-data-quality-for-a-recruiting-app/create-cross-object-formulas) you can use cross-object formulae (like you are trying to do) in reports. There are, however, some caveats, such as [this one](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000330416&type=1) so it rather depends on exactly what you're doing. Perhaps you could [edit] your question and clarify just what you are doing with this formula field?

Comment: does the running user have access to `Object2`?